# YUI.TreeView is not a constructor

Tags: treeview, yui

I am new to Javascript and YUI. When I try implementing treeview using YUI 3 (wrt http://allenrabinovich.github.com/gallery-yui-treeview/docs/), I get the following error :
yui: NOT loaded: treeview
Y.TreeView is not a constructor
   { label: 'Chapter Two' }

Please help me debug the error.Here is the code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.3.0/build/yui/yui-min.js">
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="toc" class="yui3-skin-sam">check
    </div>
    <script>
    YUI().use('treeview', function (Y) {
     var tree = new Y.TreeView({
            label: 'My Novel',
            children: [
                { label: 'Chapter One' },
                { label: 'Chapter Two' }
            ]
        });

     tree.render('#toc');
   });
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: If I use YUI-3.6.0 , it works with module  'gallery-yui-treeview' . But I want it to work with YUI-3.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

"Treeview" is a module from the gallery, you cannot load it with a YUI.use('treeview').

The correct name of this module in the gallery is **gallery-yui3treeview**, so you have to load it like this :

```
 YUI().use('gallery-yui3treeview', function (Y) {
    // Your code
 });
```

Look at this code : http://jsfiddle.net/MDUXW/